# How to create periodic HTTP error responses and timeouts?

Tags: node.js, express

I would like my express application to to respond periodically with HTTP error responses and response timeouts. I suspect this could be accomplished with a counter outside scope.

Is there a specific convention or framework (intercepting the request) to do this?

Checking before I reinvent something.